# Proving uniform continuity in $\frac{x-2}{3x-4}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I need to test if this function $f(x) := \frac{x-2}{3x-4}$ has uniform continuity on given interval $[0,\frac{4}{3})$. I think it isn't uniformly continuous, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Of course it isn't because your function has got a vertical asymptote, which means that you can obtain an arbitrarily large $|f(x) -f(y)|$ with arbitrarily small $|x-y|$, at the neighbourhood of $x = \frac{4}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (i) A function continuous on $(a,b) \in \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ if and only if it can be extended continuously to the end points i.e. it is continuous on $[a,b]$ . (A very well known result, but you can also try to prove it, it's not difficult to prove)

(ii) Your function is not continuous at $x = \frac{4}{3}$ .